# Finding a good distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm given the following problem: There are a mouse and two chickens in a cage. The probability that each of the animals escape from the cage in the next hour is $0.3$. We wait an hour and observe what there is in the cage.

- How is the random variable $X:=$"# of animals left in the cage" distributed?

  ---

I made a table to organize this distribution:
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 X & 0&1&2&3\\
\hline
P(X=x)&&&0.3&\\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{align}

I don't know how to fill the other slots. What's the probability that $2$ animals escape? Take into account that the sum of the slots should be $1$. I tried a binomial but that doesn't make much sense. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each animal escapes independently, then $X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n=3$ and $p=0.7$. Hence $$P(X=x)=\dbinom{3}{x}0.7^x0.3^{3-x}$$ for $x=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: I thought about that, But wouldn't $P(X=2)=$probability of one animal escaping from the cage$=0.3$?

Comment: No, it is not correct. There are $3$ animals, so either of them can escape which makes the probability not equal to $0.3$. Similarly for the rest

Comment: So my table is wrong haha. Ok thanks.

Comment: $P(X=0)$ is the probability, that no animal is in the cage. This is $0.3^3$. This is not what your distribution is calculating.

Comment: @calculus Yes, it is the other way round. Thanks